# How to check if LiveData or MutableLiveData has been set a value?

Tags: java, android-studio

How can I check if a value has been set to a LiveData? I want to do this because if I haven't set a value yet, I will set a starting value, and from this starting value I will get the next one.

```java
myMutable.getValue() !== null
```

I want to do something like this.

Comment: I am using a try/catch for now but that is so "wrong"

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating the LiveData?

If so, you can pass the initial value into the constructor upon creation.

Example:

```java
LiveData<Integer> liveData = new LiveData<>(1);
//liveData.getValue() == 1
```

If not, you can check if the LiveData has a value set just as you specified but with the `!=` operator.
`!==` is not a valid java operator.